# how do you make an android activity sleep and implement after the sleep period while switching onto another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there a way in which I can have an android activity to sleep instead of the entire application going to sleep.
I want the original activity to wait for 10 seconds and implement the code in it while I am using the next activity. However, using Thread.sleep(), the entire application goes to sleep. Is there any other way to do this apart from Thread.sleep()?

`try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }`

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548864/how-to-make-an-android-program-wait

Comment: Do you want to sleep because you want to do an operation in the background? Or does the user need to perform a specific task in a certain time?

Comment: I want it to sleep to perform an operation in the background but launch again at the end of the operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply launch the other activity.  Android will pause the first activity for you.  Android will invoke that activity's "onPause" method when this happens.

I suggest you read up on the Android Activity Lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html.

Or if you want the activity launch to happen at some point in the future, try using a timer task: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to frame a proper question around what I want. I want it to pause for a specific time period after which it should launch while I am using another activity.

Comment: What are your expectations for what should happen during this "pause".  Can the user still interact with the current activity?

Comment: Yes, she should be able to interact with the current activity

Comment: See the above answer.  I added a suggestion about using a Java TimerTask.  This sounds like what you want.